# CSV, Searching A String, Get Proper Information, Writing Correct Info In Correct Format

Tags: python, string, csv

I'm relatively new to stack overflow, so please bear with me.  I, additionally, apologize for the title and any ambiguity, etc.

So, here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm taking a raw data file, in .CSV format, which contains plays for
NBA games for an entire season.

The code, based on the game, creates a new file with the appropriate
title for the game.  It, then, reads each line.

Each line contains the game id, the line number (irrelevant), the time
remaining, and the 'play info'.

I have included an example below (Example 1).

The information that needs to be written, which is found below (Example 2),
has the 10 players on the court for:

- the time the play was recorded
- the period
- the time remaining in the period
- the event type
- if there is an assist
- the player credited with the assist
- if there is a foul
- the person who was fouled

etc.

The 'player' heading designates for whom the initial play was
recorded (ie. if a a player made a 'shot' that players name is
recorded).  The team, for which the play was recorded, is also
written.

Example 1:

```
GameID, LineNumber, TimeRemaining,  Entry

20071030HOULAL, 1,  0:48:00,        Start of 1st Quarter
20071030HOULAL, 2,  0:48:00,        Jump Ball Brown vs Yao
20071030HOULAL, 3,  0:47:42,        [LAL] Walton Jump Shot: Missed
20071030HOULAL, 4,  0:47:41,        [LAL] Brown Rebound (Off:1 Def:0)
20071030HOULAL, 5,  0:47:29,        [LAL] Bryant Jump Shot: Missed
20071030HOULAL, 6,  0:47:28,        [HOU] Alston Rebound (Off:0 Def:1)
20071030HOULAL, 7,  0:47:06,        [HOU] Yao Jump Shot: Missed
```

Example 2:

```
a1(away),a2(away), a3(away), a4, a5, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, period,time,team, etype, assist, away, block, entered, home, left, num, opponent, outof, player, points,possession, reason, result, steal
```

(represents the values stored for each row in the csv file - too confusing to try to include sample data)

The problem is this:

For each team, there's a player roster. My code gets the player
roster, and then creates a roster using only the players' last name,
(that's how the player name is recorded.)

The first problem arises when accumulating all 10 players for each
team, who are on the court.

I use an accumulator to store the play data until all 10 players are
recorded, and then write the play data, adding in the 10 players.

The problem is some players get 'skipped', when the checks are
performed on the variables designated as players being on the court.

For instance, there is a play recorded for Luther Head, who plays for
Houston, but he never gets recorded to `a1, a2,
a3, a4` or `a5` (The away team for the current game).

Here is how I have the "checks" set up, with `firstPlayer` being the
person the play was recorded for and `secondPlayer` being an
additional player that, for example an assist, was recorded for:

```
if team == homeTeam:
    if h1 == ' ' and firstPlayer != h2 and firstPlayer != h3 and firstPlayer != h4 and firstPlayer != h5:
        h1 = firstPlayer
    if h2 == ' ' and firstPlayer != h1 and firstPlayer != h3 and firstPlayer != h4 and firstPlayer != h5:
        h2 = firstPlayer
    if h3 == ' ' and firstPlayer != h1 and firstPlayer != h2 and firstPlayer != h4 and firstPlayer != h5:
        h3 = firstPlayer
    if h4 == ' ' and firstPlayer != h1 and firstPlayer != h2 and firstPlayer != h3 and firstPlayer != h5:
        h4 = firstPlayer
    if h5 == ' ' and firstPlayer != h1 and firstPlayer != h2 and firstPlayer != h3 and firstPlayer != h4:
        h5 = firstPlayer               

if team == visitingTeam:
    if a1 == ' ' and firstPlayer != a2 and firstPlayer != a3 and firstPlayer != a4 and firstPlayer != a5:
        a1 = firstPlayer
    if a2 == ' ' and firstPlayer != a1 and firstPlayer != a3 and firstPlayer != a4 and firstPlayer != a5:
        a2 = firstPlayer
    if a3 == ' ' and firstPlayer != a1 and firstPlayer != a2 and firstPlayer != a4 and firstPlayer != a5:
        a3 = firstPlayer
    if a4 == ' ' and firstPlayer != a1 and firstPlayer != a2 and firstPlayer != a3 and firstPlayer != a5:
        a4 = firstPlayer
    if a5 == ' ' and firstPlayer != a1 and firstPlayer != a2 and firstPlayer != a3 and firstPlayer != a4:
        a5 = firstPlayer

if etype != 'sub':  <<<<----This type of event is diffent
    if team == homeTeam and secondPlayer != ' ':
        if h1 == ' ' and secondPlayer != h2 and secondPlayer != h3 and secondPlayer != h4 and secondPlayer != h5:
            h1 = secondPlayer
        if h2 == ' ' and secondPlayer != h1 and secondPlayer != h3 and secondPlayer != h4 and secondPlayer != h5:
            h2 = secondPlayer 
        if h3 == ' ' and secondPlayer != h1 and secondPlayer != h2 and secondPlayer != h4 and secondPlayer != h5:
            h3 = secondPlayer 
        if h4 == ' ' and secondPlayer != h1 and secondPlayer != h2 and secondPlayer != h3 and secondPlayer != h5:
            h4 = secondPlayer 
        if h5 == ' ' and secondPlayer != h1 and secondPlayer  != h2 and secondPlayer != h3 and secondPlayer != h4:
            h5 = secondPlayer

    if team == visitingTeam and secondPlayer != ' ':
        if a1 == ' ' and secondPlayer != a2 and secondPlayer != a3 and secondPlayer != a4 and secondPlayer != a5:
            a1 = secondPlayer
        if a2 == ' ' and secondPlayer != a1 and secondPlayer != a3 and secondPlayer != a4 and secondPlayer != a5:
            a2 = secondPlayer
        if a3 == ' ' and secondPlayer != a1 and secondPlayer != a2 and secondPlayer != a4 and secondPlayer != a5:
            a3 = secondPlayer
        if a4 == ' ' and secondPlayer != a1 and secondPlayer != a2 and secondPlayer != a3 and secondPlayer != a5:
            a4 = secondPlayer
        if a5 == ' ' and secondPlayer != a1 and secondPlayer != a2 and secondPlayer != a3 and secondPlayer != a4:
            a5 = secondPlayer
```

I guess that is really the only problem I have.

Although, I would like to find a better way to search the string and
obtain the information.

To obtain the players, I allocate the first half of the string to one
variable and the second half to another.  Then I split the string `(sep
= ' ')`, so it's in a list.

Then I check each string to see if a word
is `==` to any of the players in the roster, depending on which team
the play was recorded for.

If it's the first string, that player gets assigned the `firstPlayer`
variable, if it's the second, that player gets assigned the
`secondPlayer` variable.

When I search for the `etype` (event type), I just search the string with expressions like:

```
if 'Shot' in string:
   etype = 'shot'
   player = firstPlayer
   if 'Assist' in string:
       assist = secondPlayer
```

...and so on for the various event types.

Please let me know if you need additional info to help answer this question.

Comment: Sorry- the first part of the code didn't get included with the rest of the code!  It is the same as the first part listed, except 'if team == homeTeam', with the "a"'s replaced with "h"'s....

Comment: *Oh god... it's full of ifs!*

Comment: @MikeLash I've edited it for you. You have to put a blank line before your (indented) code. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: By the way @MikeLash it's not too confusing to include a sample of the second csv, but to make it easier, I'd suggest you paste a sample into https://gist.github.com or http://pastie.org and share the URL here.

Comment: Yes, full of 'ifs' - I was on the fence about using 'elif'...

@furins - Thank you for editing!

Comment: I may be missing something but where's the roster? (or is that the if blocks?)

Comment: I elected to not include the roster, as I didn't think it was relevant.  If you think it will help I can add it.

Comment: If you mention it in the question and use it for your ultimate result, I think it's relevant.

Comment: btw you can surely define a function instead of repeating ifs, and I suggest you to store your data in a list like a[1], a[2], a[3] so you can use `if secondPlayer not in a`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e6abf3e15c9328a521f9

This is the sample output file.  Thank you for the links @Slomojo

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ff9ad47f8b8a3c1d6ef7

This is the roster for HOU.

Comment: I've simplified your code, to reduce all that ifs. This is not the answer to your question, but If you need it, here it is: https://gist.github.com/furins/064a2842ac38f67ccc36

Comment: I've broken down your question to make it easier to read...

Comment: Thank you for the code and for the edits!

Comment: ahh, can't make the text format correctly in the comment box!

Comment: You can use `\`your code goes here\`` to enclose code.

Comment: @furins Thank you for the help with simplifying my code.  I added an `and len(givenlist) < 5` argument.  Currently working on the accumulator, since that seems to be where the problem is coming from.  The problem is that, if a player is subbed in or out before all five players are obtained for a team, than when the list gets full, and is written along with the accumulated plays, the player who was subbed out is not accounted for in those plays... maybe a new thread for this problem...

Comment: What are all these `a1`s and `h2`s, etc. You should probably use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  They are meaningful within the realm of how the data is expected to be within the file.  As I am doing this for a professor's research, the format of the output file and, subsequently, the header of that output file, were told/given to me.  I, therefore, created 'meaningful' variables for myself, as they pertain to the data file.  So the variable a1, directly corresponds to the person who will be written under the column heading a1.  I allude to what they mean in and around 'example 2' above- a1 represents the player 1 for the away team, a2 the second, etc.